# Selecting the Nearest First

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, nearest

Imagine I have the following list

```
list = Transpose[{Range[10], RandomInteger[3, 10]}]

Out[]= {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 3}, {7, 2}, {8, 3}, {9, 0}, {10, 1}}
```

Now, I want to select the first element of `list` for which the second entry in such element is nearest to a given number `n`. For example, if `n = 1.3`, the "nearest" elements are

```
{{3, 1}, {5, 1}, {10, 1}}
```

And thus the first element is `{3, 1}`. In some sense, I want to completely ignore the first entry of each pair.

Any idea how to do this?

**My approach:** In a not-so-elegant manner, I could simply do

```
dn = Min[Abs[n - #] & /@ list[[All, 2]]]
SelectFirst[list, Abs[#[[2]] - n] == dn &]

Out[]= {3, 1}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: `nf = Nearest[list[[All, 2]] -> "Index"]; First@list[[nf[1.3]]]`

Comment: or even like this: `nf = Nearest[list, DistanceFunction -> Last@*Abs@*Subtract];
First@nf[{, 1.3}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 3}, {7, 2}, {8, 3}, {9, 0}, {10, 1}};

n = 1.3;
```

Using `FirstPosition` and `Extract`

```
p = FirstPosition[#, Min @ #] & @ Abs[n - Last /@ list]
```

{3}

```
Extract[list, p]
```

{3, 1}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 3}, {7, 2}, {8, 3}, {9, 0}, {10, 1}};
```

---

Using `LengthWhile`:

```
Module[{n, l},
n = 1.3; l = Abs[n - Last /@ list];
Extract[list, {LengthWhile[l, # != Min@l &] + 1}]]

(*{3, 1}*)
```